# Vue 3 directives – how to push array of items to directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Since there's no `IntersectionObserver` library for Vue 3, I'd like to implement my own little solution.

I read about directives, and from what I understand it's the right direction. (?)

My local directive:

```
directives: {
    'lazyload': {
      mounted(el) {
        if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {        
          let intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
              if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                const lazyImage = entry.target;
                
                // set data-srcset as image srcset
                lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.getAttribute('data-srcset');
                
                // add class after image has loaded
                lazyImage.addEventListener('load', () => {
                  lazyImage.classList.add('is-lazyloaded');
                };
                // unobserve after
                lazyLoadItemObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
              }
            });
          });
          
          // observe every image
          const lazyLoadItems = document.querySelectorAll('[lazyload]')
          
          lazyLoadItems.forEach((lazyImage) => {
            lazyLoadItemObserver.observe(lazyImage);
          });
  
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The vanilla way would be to make an array out of every `<IMG>` element that has the `attribute` `lazyload` for instance. The thing I don't get is how to make an array out of every `<IMG>` that has the `v-lazyload` binding.

Something like "if this image has the v-lazyload binding, put it into the IntersectionObserver's array." I might understand it wrong though.

So I'd like to come up with a directive which sets one single `IntersectionObserver` which observes an array of all the images that have the `v-lazyload` binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `v-lazyload` directive will be on the target elements already, so no need to query the document.

In the directive's `mounted` hook, you can attach an `IntersectionObserver` instance to the parent node if it doesn't already exist. Then, use that instance to observe the target element (also unobserve the element in `unmounted`):

```js
directives: {
  mounted(el) {
    el.parentNode.lazyLoadItemObserver = el.parentNode.lazyLoadItemObserver || new IntersectionObserver(/*...*/)
    el.parentNode.lazyLoadItemObserver.observe(el)
  },
  unmounted(el) {
    el.parentNode.lazyLoadItemObserver.unobserve(el)
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lazy-loading-imgs-with-vue-3-directives-fuqj5?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Hi Toni, thanks for the Demo and the insight! But the thing is that I want to avoid having an Intersection Observer for every single image element individually but 1 Intersection Observer on the root body element which observes every image that has the lazyload directive.

Comment: Ok. Then you could use the same approach I outlined, but instead of `el.parentNode`, use `document.body`.

Comment: Ah, yes. My issue was that with my code it created an IntersectionObserver for every single image because I didn't check if one already existed like you. Thanks and have a nice new year!